# how to count the number of item in a loop

Tags: php

With the code below I am trying to count how many items I have in my loop by sort and then the total of everything

if I return for example

1 item 77777

3 items 88888

5 items 99999

3 items 2005

5 items 2002

9 items 2001

the total should be 26

The expected result should be
1 item 77777

3 items 88888

5 items 99999

17 other items

total 26 items
But I only get 7

```
$datanom = $commande;
$decodenom = json_decode($datanom);
$mailData1 = "";
$mailData2 = "";
$mailData3 = "";
$mailData4 = "";

$counts = [];
foreach ($decodenom  as $curr_elementnom) {
    $fieldName = $curr_elementnom->nom;
    $fieldQty = $curr_elementnom->quantite;
    $fieldPrice = $curr_elementnom->prix;
    $fieldimg = $curr_elementnom->url;
    if ( $fieldQty != 0 ) {
        if ($fieldPrice != 0) {
            if ($fieldName == 77777) {
                $input1 =   '<div style ="border:solid;"> 
           <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> voici le nom</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldName . '</div>
            <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> qanditée</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldQty . '</div >
                 </div><br><br><br>';
                $mailData1 .= $input1;
                @$counts[$fieldName]++;
            }
            elseif ($fieldName == 88888) {
                $input2 =   '<div style ="border:solid;"> 
           <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> voici le nom</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldName . '</div>
            <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> qanditée</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldQty . '</div >
                 </div><br><br><br>';
                $mailData2 .= $input2;
                @$counts[$fieldName]++;
            }
            elseif ($fieldName == 99999) {
                $input3 =   '<div style ="border:solid;"> 
            <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> qanditée</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldQty . '</div >
           <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> voici le nom</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldName . '</div>
                 </div><br><br><br>';
                   $mailData .= $input3;
                @$counts[$fieldName]++;
                 
                $mailData3 .= $input3;
                @$counts['other']++;
            }
              else  {
                $input4 ='<div style ="border:solid;"> 
            <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> qanditée</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldQty . '</div >
           <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> voici le nom</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldName . '</div>
                 </div><br><br><br>';
                   $mailData4 .= $input4;
                   @$counts['other']++;
            }
        } 
    }
}
var_dump ($mailData1);
var_dump ($mailData2);
var_dump ($mailData3);
var_dump ($mailData4);
var_dump ($counts);
$totalperles = array_sum($counts);
```

here is the echo of order

```
[{"nom":2005,"prix":1.1,"quantite":"1","url":"https://phil.pecheperle.be/image-perles/perle-verre-peche-gardon-2005.JPG"},{"nom":2003,"prix":0.55,"quantite":"5","url":"https://phil.pecheperle.be/image-perles/perle-verre-peche-gardon-2003.JPG"},{"nom":2002,"prix":0.55,"quantite":"9","url":"https://phil.pecheperle.be/image-perles/perle-verre-peche-gardon-2002.JPG"},{"nom":77777,"prix":11,"quantite":"1","url":"https://phil.pecheperle.be/image-perles/pack_debutant-peche-perle-redimensionnee.jpg"},{"nom":88888,"prix":22,"quantite":"3","url":"https://phil.pecheperle.be/image-perles/pack_confirme-peche-perle-redimensionnee.jpg"},{"nom":99999,"prix":33,"quantite":"5","url":"https://phil.pecheperle.be/image-perles/mega-pack-peche-perle-redimensionnee.jpg"}]1
```

Comment: Use an associative array containing the counters.

Comment: Why do you do `$data = $commande;$decode = json_decode($data);` instead of simply `$data =  json_decode($commande);`?

Comment: I don't know I'm a beginner

Comment: Beginner or not, you had to have a reason. Do you think there's a reason you can't use some variables in `json_decode()`?

Comment: no indeed none, I could have done so it's true

Answer (score 1):

Use an associative array whose keys are the item numbers. Then add the value of `$fieldQty` to the appropriate element.

Also, the last `else if` should just be `else` to handle all other values.

```
$data = $commande;
$decode = json_decode($data);
$mailData1 = "";
$mailData2 = "";
$mailData3 = "";
$mailData4 = "";
$counts = [];
foreach ($decode  as $curr_element) {
    $fieldName = $curr_element->nom;
    $fieldQty = $curr_element->quantite;
    $fieldPrice = $curr_element->prix;
    $fieldimg = $curr_element->url;
    if ( $fieldQty != 0 ) {
        if ($fieldPrice != 0) {
            if ($fieldName == 77777) {
                $input1 =   '<div style ="border:solid;"> 
           <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> voici le nom</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldName . '</div>
            <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> qanditée</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldQty . '</div >
                 </div><br><br><br>';
                $mailData1 .= $input1;
                @$counts[$fieldName] += $fieldQty;
            }
            elseif ($fieldName == 88888) {
                $input2 =   '<div style ="border:solid;"> 
           <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> voici le nom</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldName . '</div>
            <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> qanditée</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldQty . '</div >
                 </div><br><br><br>';
                $mailData2 .= $input2;
                @$counts[$fieldName] += $fieldQty;
            }
            elseif ($fieldName == 99999) {
                $input3 =   '<div style ="border:solid;"> 
            <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> qanditée</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldQty . '</div >
           <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> voici le nom</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldName . '</div>
                 </div><br><br><br>';
                $mailData3 .= $input3;
                @$counts['other'] += $fieldQty;
            } else {
                $input4 ='<div style ="border:solid;"> 
            <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> qanditée</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldQty . '</div >
           <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> voici le nom</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldName . '</div>
                 </div><br><br><br>';
                   $mailData4 .= $input4;
                   @$counts['other'] += $fieldQty;
        } 
    }
}
var_dump ($mailData1);
var_dump ($mailData2);
var_dump ($mailData3);
var_dump ($mailData4);
var_dump ($counts);
```

Comment: A very big thank you for the code but I have errors at the level of these lines
$counts[$fieldName]++;

Notice: Undefined offset:77777

Notice: Undefined offset:88888

Notice: Undefined offset:99999

Notice: Undefined offset:other

Comment: You can put `@` before all the increments, that will suppress the warning. It automatically initializes new keys to 0.

Comment: how to add the whenites of 77777 + 88888+99999+others please

Comment: I don't know what "whenites" means.

Comment: how to add the quantities ($fieldQty )of 77777 + 88888+99999+others

for example if I have 18 items for 77777 +

25 items for 88888 +

20 items for 99999 +

10 items for others

the total would make 73

Comment: `$total = array_sum($counts)`

Comment: after checks for the others it only counts 1

for example
77777 items 1****

88888 items 2****

99999 items 3****

2006 items 1****

2005 items 1****

2003 items 1*****



total: 7 items

Comment: Please post sample JSON in the question.

Comment: I will open a new question it will be easier

Comment: here I have asked my question

Comment: The question has been closed as a duplicate of this once, since the code is the same. Why didn't you include the JSON like I asked?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking me maybe this
var command = JSON.stringify(basket);

Comment: Just the output of `echo $commande;`

Comment: Thank you very much for the help I put the echo in my question

Comment: Your JSON has the following `nom` values: `2001`, `2003`, `2006`, `77777`, `88888`, `99999`. So the counts for 77777, 88888, and 99999 are each 1, and the counts for the others are 3. So the total is 6.

Comment: I think you don't want to count the items, you want to add up the `quantite` values.

Comment: sorry i was distracted

Comment: yes here is adding the quantity-values.

Comment: You've changed the question to match my answer. Now how is anyone supposed to understand what I was answering?

Comment: I don't know but from the beginning I wanted to add the quantity-values

Answer (score 0):

```
$datanom = $commande;
$decodenom = json_decode($datanom);
$mailData1 = "";
$mailData2 = "";
$mailData3 = "";
$mailData4 = "";
$mailData = "";
$counts = [];
foreach ($decodenom  as $curr_elementnom) {
    $fieldName = $curr_elementnom->nom;
    $fieldQty = $curr_elementnom->quantite;
        $fieldName7 = $curr_elementnom->nom;
    $fieldQty7 = $curr_elementnom->quantite;
            $fieldName8 = $curr_elementnom->nom;
    $fieldQty8 = $curr_elementnom->quantite;
            $fieldName9 = $curr_elementnom->nom;
    $fieldQty9 = $curr_elementnom->quantite;
    $fieldPrice = $curr_elementnom->prix;
    $fieldimg = $curr_elementnom->url;
    if ( $fieldQty != 0 ) {
        if ($fieldPrice != 0) {
            if ($fieldName == 77777) {
                $input1 =   '<div style ="border:solid;"> 
           <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> voici le nom</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldName . '</div>
            <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> qanditée</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldQty7 . '</div >
                 </div><br><br><br>';
                $mailData1 .= $input1;
                @$counts[$fieldName]++;
            }
            elseif ($fieldName == 88888) {
                $input2 =   '<div style ="border:solid;"> 
           <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> voici le nom</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldName8 . '</div>
            <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> qanditée</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldQty8 . '</div >
                 </div><br><br><br>';
                $mailData2 .= $input2;
                @$counts[$fieldName]++;
            }
            elseif ($fieldName == 99999) {
                $input3 =   '<div style ="border:solid;"> 
            <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> qanditée</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldQty9 . '</div >
           <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> voici le nom</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldName9 . '</div>
                 </div><br><br><br>';
                   $mailData .= $input3;
                @$counts[$fieldName]++;
                 
                $mailData3 .= $input3;
                @$counts['other']++;
            }
              else  {
                $input4 ='<div style ="border:solid;"> 
            <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> qanditée</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldQty . '</div >
           <div style ="float: left;width: 50%;"> voici le nom</div >
           <div style =""> ' . $fieldName . '</div>
                 </div><br><br><br>';
                   $mailData4 .= $input4;
                   @$counts['other']++;
            }
        } 
    }
}

$totalperles =$fieldQty7 + $fieldQty8 + $fieldQty9 + $fieldQty  ;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).